# Error Bars Do NOT Match Multiple Linear Regression Model

Tags: lme4, standard-error, significance

I am trying to fit a linear mixed model using the lme4 package. Every model I try says that 2a and 1a are not significant.

I am curious as to why the error bars do not match what I am seeing in the lmer output. Specifically, why would 2a and 1a have no significant difference when there is no overlap between the error bars.

[I am not allowed to embed a picture yet so here is graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK7p1.png)

Comment: I wonder if your question would be better on [Cross Validated.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Will do, thank you.